# Getting name of previous test step of type Rest Request in SoapUI groovy script

Tags: rest, groovy, properties, soapui

I'm using groovy script to transfer a certain property from the response of a REST request like this:

```
def setCookie = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["SubmitCompleteDeviceRegistration"].testRequest.response.responseHeaders["Set-Cookie"]
def global = com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.globalProperties

re = /(SESSION_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN=[A-Za-z0-9_-]+;)/
matcher = ( setCookie =~ re )
def cookie = matcher[0][0]

global.setPropertyValue("SESSION_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN","$cookie")

return cookie
```

Now what I want to do is make the name of the above teststep, "SubmitCompleteDeviceRegistration", variable, so I can use the transfer for various REST-Requests.

The name of this variable TestStep should equal the name of the previous TestStep **of the RestRequest type**.

How can I go about defining the TestStep that equals this condition?

I'm trying to use something like

```
def prevGroovyTestStep =       
testRunner.testCase.findPreviousStepOfType(testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName
("SubmitCompleteDeviceRegistration"),RestRequest)

log.info(prevGroovyTestStep.getName())
```

But I'm not sure how to implement this.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: [@Jose Kivits](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5780662/jos%c3%a9-kivits), do you need just previous step? or it should be previous step and matching Rest step? And what do you want if the previous step is not of Rest Step type?

Answer (score 0):

**Getting the previous step name**

```groovy
def previousStepName = context.testCase.testStepList[context.currentStepIndex - 1].name
log.info "Previous step name is : ${previousStepName}"
```

**Getting the previous step name if its type is Rest Request**

```groovy
def testStep = context.testCase.testStepList[context.currentStepIndex - 1]
def previousStepName
if (testStep instanceof com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.RestTestRequestStep) {
    previousStepName = testStep.name
} else {
    log.error "Previous step is not of Rest Request Type"
}
if (previousStepName) {
    log.info "Previous step name is : ${previousStepName}"
}
```

If type does not match in the above case, it will log the error message.

---

**UPDATE** - updating as per the latest comments from the author of this question. The below one helps all your need and the above may not needed any more.

1. Add a custom property for the test case, whose name is `STEP_NAME` and its value is the **test step name** to which *http header* needs to be added. As you commented, the last test step name in this case.
2. Go the *request test step* where you are getting the Cookie as response header.
3. Add an assertion of type **Script Assertion** and have the below code. Note that, you need to *modify* the *test step* name to which you want to add the *request header* `Cookie`. Using the ***place holder*** for now.

```groovy
/**Below script should be used as script assertion for first test request step
* Assumes below
* a. test response contains http header called 'Set-Cookie'
* b. other request needs to send http header called 'Cookie'
* In case if there is any change in the two header names you may need to 
* change its references below
**/
def responseCookieKey = 'Set-Cookie'
def requestCookieKey = 'Cookie'


def setHttpHeaders(String nextStepName, def headers) {
    def nextRequest = context.testCase.testSteps[nextStepName].httpRequest
    def existingHeaders = nextRequest.requestHeaders
    headers.each {
        existingHeaders[it.key] = it.value
    }
    nextRequest.requestHeaders = existingHeaders
}


if (messageExchange.responseHeaders.containsKey(responseCookieKey)) {
  log.info "Found Cookie in the response headers"
  def cookiez = messageExchange.responseHeaders[responseCookieKey]
  assert null != cookiez, "Response does not contain Cookie"  
  def headers = [(requestCookieKey) : (cookiez)]
  setHttpHeaders(context.testCase.getProvertyValue('STEP_NAME'), headers)
} else {
  log.error "Not Found Cookie in the response headers"
}
```

Comment: Hi Rao, 

Thanks for the reply. I'm sorry, I propably didn't define what I needed clearly enough. 

What I need is the last executed teststep of the rest request type, i.e, it can be 3 steps removed from the groovy teststep, as long as it's a rest request. I'm thinking the script should start with the previous step and if this step isn't a rest request, it continues with the previous step, until the condition is met. In case the condition is not met it should just continue without logging an error. Could you adjust the script to meet these requirements?

Comment: Can you explain what is your use case rather or what you are trying to achieve, there may exists other or better solutions?

Comment: Ok, looks the summary of the question is causing the confusion. If you need to extract the header value (could be session id or cookie) and assign it to some global property. Is that what your question is ?

Comment: Yes, I'm indeed extracting a header value (cookie) and assigning this to a property. What I want to do is extract a cookie from the response of a REST teststep's response so I can use it in a following REST request. I'm using groovy script to achieve this, but every time I copy this teststep to a new testcase I have to adjust the script according to the name of the test step it needs to extract the cookie from. This teststep will always be the last executed REST teststep, which is why I'm trying to find a way to easily identify this teststep's name and use it as a variable in the script.

Comment: Ideally I wouldn't even have to copy the groovy teststep to each testcase but just add it as an independent testcase which can be run from within every testcase (Run testcase > point to the groovy teststep), but other approaches might work just as well.

Comment: Ok, updating the answer as per the comments, please  try that one.