# Soap Webservices giving HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

Tags: soap, soapui

I am trying to use a Soap Web Services expose by the server. I am using SoapUI to call the web services.

#### URL

`https://10.234.60.34:9443/services/ExecutionManagerAdminService.ExecutionManagerAdminServiceHttpsSoap12Endpoint/`

```
// Request:
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:adm="http://admin.manager.execution.event.carbon.wso2.org">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <adm:getAllDomains/>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

// Response
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=E645AC1CD9E31CF1D71405C416A3A253; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Server: WSO2 Carbon Server
Date: Mon, 11 Apr 2016 12:48:34 GMT
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="WSO2 Complex Event Processor"
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

I have created sessionId using the jar provided by the vendor and providing the it in the header.I tried providing it as  `"SessionID" : "ED8460F7C46A2DD807E2F2CF515E2EBB"`.I also tried like `"Cookie" : "ED8460F7C46A2DD807E2F2CF515E2EBB"`. Both failed and giving `401 UnAuthorized`.

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34752350/getting-name-of-previous-test-step-of-type-rest-request-in-soapui-groovy-script) existing answer(refer to the UPDATE part of it).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass the `SessionID` inside the cookie. However you don't replace cookies contents with your `SessionID`, you add it to the string.

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=E645AC1CD9E31CF1D71405C416A3A253; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SessionID=ED8460F7C46A2DD807E2F2CF515E2EBB
```

The format for cookies is:

```
Set-Cookie: <name>=<value>[; <name>=<value>]...
[; expires=<date>][; domain=<domain_name>]
[; path=<some_path>][; secure][; httponly]
```