# How to Set up Cookie in SOAPUI by logging in from the browser directly

Tags: soapui

I am using latest SOAP-UI latest version and my scenario is like below :

1. Open the browser and login to website.
2. After login the browser will generate some cookie.
3. And I have a webservice which will only give results once I provide this cookie to the webservice.

Now my questions:

- Is there any way by which i can directly send that browser cookie to soapui to run the particular webservice which only runs when it receives some cookie ?
- Any SOAP UI add-on if there in the market?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34752350/getting-name-of-previous-test-step-of-type-rest-request-in-soapui-groovy-script) if this is something you are looking after.

Comment: Hi Rao, this is not my question, I am generating cookie in my browser and from there i want to transfer it to automatically to SOAP UI like in postman we can do with the help of interceptor

Comment: There should be a smooth way in web service to create token/cookie based on your credentials so that it can be used for further web service tests. I haven't seen create session using browser and then use it for web service. May be you can suggest your team the same.

Comment: By the way you should able to use `HTTP Request` type step hit the url from soapui itself instead of using external browser. Please give a try. And what you are doing currently is not general practice in my view.

Comment: Hi Rao, Thanks for your suggestion but the thing we are in time crunch and this api needs to be developed from magento and then needs to be consumed in nodejs which itself is a complex and will take 4-5 days and we don't have any but we have found out the alternative method for that case for this particular scenario we are running it in postman using interceptor addon